# Using Object tags in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have this html code for embedding a video in an aspx page:

```
    <OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
<PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="videofilename.wmv">
<PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="false">
<PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
<PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
<EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="videofilename.wmv" NAME="MediaPlayer"
WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0"> </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

The thing is, I want to set its parameters from my C# code-behind (f.e., the path to the file to be played).

I know I should add `runat="server"` but that's not the only thing.  The code-behind doesn't recognize any element of the type MediaPlayer no matter what.  (I'm trying to access it from my `Page_Load(..)`)

How should I do this?

10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `HtmlGenericControl`. You can set the attributes through the `Attributes` property via your codebehind. And add the sub-elements through `Controls`.

```
HtmlGenericControl obj = new HtmlGenericControl("object");
HtmlGenericControl embedTag = new HtmlGenericControl("embed");
embedTag.Attributes["type"] = "application/x-mplayer2";

obj.Controls.Add(embedTag);

flashPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no ASP.NET control for the OBJECT tag, so you have to generate its HTML yourself. There are two simple ways to do this. The first way is to use <% %> tags in your ASPX file, like this:

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" 
STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject"> 
<PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="<% =FileName %>"> 
...
</OBJECT>
```

The other way is to create a LiteralControl in your codebehind, and set its HTML to whatever you want:

```
LiteralControl myObject = new LiteralControl();
myObject.Text =
    @"<OBJECT ID='MediaPlayer' WIDTH='192' HEIGHT='190' CLASSID='CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95' STANDBY='Loading Windows Media Player components...' TYPE='application/x-oleobject'>
    <PARAM NAME='FileName' VALUE='" + FileName + "'>
    ...
    </OBJECT>';";
Page.Controls.Add(myObject);
```