# Adding Object or changing its parameter programmatically in C# / ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, windows-media-player

I want to embed Windows Media Player into my ASP.NET page. I do it with this code, which works fine:

```
<OBJECT id='mediaPlayer1' width="180" height="50" 
classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95' 
codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701'
standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' type='application/x-oleobject'>
<param name='fileName' value="http..">
<param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
<param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
<param name='autoStart' value="false">
<param name='showControls' value="true">
<param name ="ShowAudioControls"value="true">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
<param name='loop' value="false">
<EMBED type='application/x-mplayer2'
pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1' 
bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1' 
showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="420" height="380"
src="http..."    
autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="false">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

My problem is, that I want to change the url in my code behind, (like [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1082119.aspx/1) but it is in VB, not C#) because I load the Urls out of a database. So is there a way, where I can add this code in my c# part or -even better- to access the url from the c# part?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I searched for hours now.. and this.FindControl(mediaPlayer1); doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `Render` method.
Edit it to suite your requirements.

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("<OBJECT " 
            +"ID='" +this.ClientID + "' "
            + "name='" + this.ClientID + "' "
            +"CLASSID='CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6'" 
            +"VIEWASTEXT"
            );
        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='autostart' value='false'>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='autoplay' value='false'>");

        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='URL' value='/" + fileUrl + "/" + selectedFile + "'>");

        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='rate' value='1'>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='balance' value='0'>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='enabled' value='true'>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='enabledContextMenu' value='true'>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='fullScreen' value='false'>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='playCount' value='1'>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<PARAM name='volume' value='100'>");
        stringBuilder.Append("</OBJECT>");

        divWindowsMediaPlayer.InnerHtml = stringBuilder.ToString();

        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, of course there already was an answer I didnt see 4 hours long while searching yesterday, but just this morning.. : [Using Object tags in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980524/using-object-tags-in-asp-net?rq=1)