# Object tag requirement for a browser plugin to work

Tags: javascript

Is it required to add  tag in a page for particular plugin to work or we can add it dynamically after page gets loaded?

Comment: There is not even close to enough information in this question to answer.  Try asking about a specific browser plugin.

Comment: I am trying to develop a cross browser plugin with the help of firebreath framework which is implemented in C++. I am just curious to know is it required to embed an <object> tag in your webpage to interact with plugin or we can add it dynamically after the page gets loaded?

Comment: We'll it's possible to dynamically add an object to a web page that uses the flash plug-in so it's technically possible to make a plugin work with dynamic content.  Beyond that, it really depends upon what your plug-in is trying to do.

Comment: Ok. I was concerned about that only. So you are positive about that Object tag can be dynamically added into a webpage with the help of plugin, so that plugin itself can work?

Comment: It works for Flash plugins.

Comment: Ok.Then it should work in my case(plugin). What am I trying to do is that whenever user selects any text content on a webpage and right click on it then plugin will show some advance options and after clicking that option CSS will pop up showing some results.

Comment: Next time, include the specific thing you're trying to do rather than asking such a generic question that is hard to know how to answer.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that. Looking forward for further in-depth discussions.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843653/adding-object-or-changing-its-parameter-programmatically-in-c-sharp-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now that we have a little bit better idea what you're trying to do from your comments, it appears that the Adobe Flash plugin proves that you can dynamically add an object tag to a web page and have the plugin be connected to it as that works with Flash all the time.  So, I think it's reasonable to say that plug-ins can work with dynamically created object tags.